# Pascal Triangles with Tuples in Recursion in Python

Tags: python, recursion, tuples, pascals-triangle

I am asked to write a recursion for Pascal's triangle, with tuples.
This is my code:

```
def pascal(n):
    if n == 1:
        return (1,)
    if n == 2:
        return ((1,),(1,1))
    else:
        new_row = ()
        for i in range(-1, n-1):
            if i == -1:
                new_row = new_row + (1,)
            elif i == n - 1:
                new_row = new_row + (1,)
            else:
                a = pascal(n-1)[n-2][i] + pascal(n-2)[n-1][i+1]
                new_row = new_row + (a,)
        return pascal(n-1), new_row
```

I am getting an error that says tuple index out of range if I call `pascal(3)` or higher.

This is the trace output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tup.py", line 19, in <module>
    print pascal(3)
  File "tup.py", line 15, in pascal
    a = pascal(n-1)[n-2][i] + pascal(n-2)[n-1][i+1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: can you please post the full trace back?

Comment: could you please post the input that you are using?

Comment: Try debugging your input. Especially, after the `else:`, print out the values for `n` and `i`. That will you give you the information where you're out of range. If that doesn't give you enough information, print out the information on the tuples itself (size, content, etc.).

Comment: I would assume that your second `if`statement should probably be an `elif`( n can't be equal to 2 and 1 at the same time). This might solve the problem!

Comment: pascal(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#116>", line 1, in <module>
    pascal(3)
  File "<pyshell#115>", line 14, in pascal
    a = pascal(n-1)[n-2][i] + pascal(n-2)[n-1][i+1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Answer (score 4):

The following will work. Loop from 0 to `n-2` (exclusive) on the previous row:

```
def pascal(n):
    if n == 1:  # one base case is enough
        return ((1,),)  # return tuple of tuples to be consistent
    prev = pascal(n-1)
    new_row = [1] + [prev[-1][i]+prev[-1][i+1] for i in range(n-2)] + [1]
    return prev + tuple(new_row)

>>> pascal(2)
((1,), (1, 1))
>>> pascal(3)
((1,), (1, 1), (1, 2, 1))
>>> pascal(4)
((1,), (1, 1), (1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 3, 1))
```

Explanation: The n-th row has n elements, 2 of which are 1. Thus n-2 of the elements are formed by appropriate sums in the loop, hence the range.

Comment: thanks for the help, but would there be a way without having to use the tuple() function?

Comment: Well, you can keep concatenating the literals as you did before, but that is even worse performance wise. This is the mere `tuple` constructor that is passed an appropriate generator expression.

Comment: @LinJinjia SInce they are immutable, tuples are not ideal to build incrementally. If anything, you should keep `append`ing to a list and turn it into a tuple in the end.